# MySQL return items with joined tables

Tags: mysql, date, join

I'm working on a project where I have to look for every area that's free on a specific moment but I'm kinda confused on how to do it.

I've got 2 tables. **Area** and **Reservation**.

Area has:
id,
name

Reservation has:
id,
area_id,
start_date,
end_date

What I want to return are all Areas that don't have a Reservations on a specific date. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to check date in `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
$date = '2016-2-2';
SELECT a.name
FROM area AS a,
     reservation AS r
WHERE (r.start_date <> '$date' OR r.end_date <> '$date')
```

Assuming that your date format is `Y-m-d` in your database.

Comment: This doesn't seme to work. When there are no reservations at all, it's not returning anything while it's suppose to be returning everything. When only one area has a reservation, it adds the same start_date to all  other areas.

Comment: it will be helpful if you add dummy data with expected result

Comment: Lets say Ive got 3 areas, Area A, Area B, Area C. Area A has a reservation between 2016-2-2 and 2016-2-4. Area B and C don't have any. I want it to only return B and C when I request all Areas that are free on 2016-2-3.

Comment: then what should be the output?

Comment: Just the names of the Areas is fine. At the moment, returns none of  them if I request 2016-2-3 and all 3 of them when I request 2016-2-5

Comment: @JasonLie i think this should work:`SELECT a.name
FROM area AS a,
     reservation AS r
WHERE (r.start_date <> '$date' OR r.end_date <> '$date')`

Comment: It does work for the areas that do have a reservation. But the areas that don't have one, only return when the one with a reservation return.

Comment: Are you using String concatenation for building the query? This time is a Date which is a bit safer but please avoid. It open you application to SQL Injections. And it has worse performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM area AS a
LEFT JOIN reservation AS r ON r.area_id = a.id 
AND :myDate between r.start_date AND r.end_date 
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```